# iOS Swift app - SIGABRT: Cannot expell bindable from a binder which doesn't own it

Tags: ios, swift

Since iOS 15.5 I am receiving a large number of crash logs from my app with no app specific code.

My app is written in Swift.

The error says

> SIGABRT: Cannot expell bindable from a binder which doesn't own it

The symbolicated crash log is as follows

```
CoreFoundation  __exceptionPreprocess + 220
libobjc.A.dylib objc_exception_throw + 56
Foundation  -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 200
UIKitCore   -[_UIContextBinder expellBindable:] + 384
UIKitCore   -[UIWindowScene _detachWindow:] + 264
UIKitCore   -[_UIScreenBasedWindowScene _detachWindow:] + 48
UIKitCore   -[UIWindowScene _attachWindow:] + 116
UIKitCore   -[UIWindow _setWindowHostingScene:] + 252
UIKitCore   -[UIWindow setWindowScene:] + 216
UIKitCore   _UIApplicationSceneConnectionHandler_block_invoke + 980
UIKitCore   +[UIScene _sceneForFBSScene:create:withSession:connectionOptions:] + 1060
UIKitCore   -[UIApplication _connectUISceneFromFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 1252
UIKitCore   -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 340
UIKitCore   -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 384
FrontBoardServices  -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 436
FrontBoardServices  __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.215 + 124
FrontBoardServices  -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 236
FrontBoardServices  __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 368
libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_client_callout + 16
libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 260
FrontBoardServices  __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 44
FrontBoardServices  -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 216
FrontBoardServices  -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 24
CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 204
CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 264
CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 824
CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 596
GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 160
UIKitCore   -[UIApplication _run] + 1096
UIKitCore   UIApplicationMain + 360
MyAppModule main (MyEnum.swift:16)
undefined   0x0000000105841ce4
```

Unfortunately there is no specific behaviour that I can see that leads to this, and it seems to be from looking at the stack during the app launch/resume or transition to background.

How do I begin figuring out what is going on?

This only started in iOS 15.5

**UPDATE** This seems to have stopped with iOS 17 so most likely it was an iOS internal issue.